# Code first deployment using EF targetting startup project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm reposting this question now that I have a clearer picture of the problem.  I say problem as I don't see any logical reason for this behaviour.

I have a solution which contains three projects:

**DataLayer project**

**BusinessLogicLayer project**

**Win Forms (set as the STARTUP project)**

The DataLayer project uses EF 6 and the Oracle Managed Client. I've found that although the enable-migration and add-migration target my DataLayer project successfully (either by setting the default project in the drop down in Package Manager or using the -project flag) the update-database does not.  I actually have to right click my DataLayer project and tell visual studio to set it as the startup project.

From testing it seems update-database in a code first approach is looking for the app.config in the startup project, rather than what is selected as the default project.

I want my project to have a 3 tier architecture, keeping all my database related stuff and EF tucked away in my DataLayer project.  I don't want to have to keep changing the DataLayer project to be the startup project, just to update the database.  Is this normal behaviour, or is there something I'm missing entirely?

Side notes: Using the community edition of VS, tried on two different systems, fresh projects and getting same behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tips for the -startupproject flag I was able to find a solution.

In order to use the update-database command for a project which is not the startup project you have to pass both the -projectname and -startupproject flags together on the same call e.g.:

```
update-database -project datalayer -startupproject datalayer
```